# How to put all related imports in one separate file and use it across the react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have included a fontAwesome library into my react app. now i'm trying to create a react definition file like with key value pairs. like below

```
icon_def.js

import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { fas, faMousePointer } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { far, faHandPaper, faLaugh } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'


library.add(fas, faMousePointer)
library.add(far, faHandPaper, faLaugh)

const icon = {
    faMousePointer : ["fas", "mouse-pointer"]
}
```

now is it possible to use this across react project. like below

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon.faMousePointer} className={'hi-c'} />
```

Answer (score 0):

So using this approach, you have to export icon in icon_def.js and export it whenever you wanted to use it:

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { fas, faMousePointer } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { far, faHandPaper, faLaugh } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'


library.add(fas, faMousePointer)
library.add(far, faHandPaper, faLaugh)

const icon = {
    faMousePointer : ["fas", "mouse-pointer"]
}
export default icon;
```

So whenever you wanted to us it:

```
//Sample.js
//assuming icon_def is in the root directory
import icon from "/icon_def" 
.
.
.
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon.faMousePointer} className={'hi-c'} />
```

This is the good practice. However, if you want to have access to the icon throughout your application in the browser, you can also use windows object this way:

```
windows.icon = {
    faMousePointer : ["fas", "mouse-pointer"]
}
```

And then Whenever you needs it:
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={windows.icon.faMousePointer} className={'hi-c'} />
But as it might cause conflict with other libraries it is not recommended.